# Cloudformation Init calling S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, powershell-2.0, aws-cloudformation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/rd-gateway/step2.html#existing-standalone
https://s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-reference/microsoft/rdgateway/latest/templates/rdgw-standalone.template

I'm referencing template above to create my Remote Desktop Gateway (RDGW) in existing VPC. It has QSS3BucketName, QSS3KeyPrefix in parameter section. Resources section has RDGWLaunchConfiguration references QSS3BucketName bucket again. on Setup files, it's calling the following path.

`https://${QSS3BucketName}.${QSS3Region}.amazonaws.com/${QSS3KeyPrefix}submodules/quickstart-microsoft-utilities/scripts/Unzip-Archive.ps1`

For some reason, PT30 (after30 mins it says it didn't get the required signal and rolls back. Question to the community is what do I need to store these files in the S3 buckets or templates would dump it in S3 while it's creating the stack.

I also created a bucket in S3, copied these scripts from GitHub and pasted inside the bucket in the correct order, still does not work. Kind frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

The quick start template is referencing nested templates placed at aws-quickstart S3 bucket. If we place the default values in above URL, than the exact URL we get is,

https://aws-quickstart.s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-microsoft-rdgateway/submodules/quickstart-microsoft-utilities/scripts/Unzip-Archive.ps1

You can create the stack with either default values without changing AWS quick start configuration or else you can download all the referencing templates, modify as per your requirement and place it in your own bucket. Once it is done than replace the URL value in the main template with your bucket's URL.